# INotifyPropertyChanged and the BindingList ListChanged event

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged, bindinglist

If I have a class like the one below:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BindingList<String> myList;

    public BindingList<String> MyList
    {
        get { return myList; }
        set
        {
            if (myList == value) return;
            myList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyList");
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to setup the following event handler:

```
myList.ListChanged += (object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e) => OnPropertyChanged("MyList");
```

Or is it detected?  I know that the BindingList class will look for the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on the templated type it is of so it can determine whether it should raise the ListChanged event, but I am uncertain if it works the other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `myList` field is encapsulated within your class - nothing it does is going to "bubble out" automatically. Things that bind to an instance of your class won't know about changes in `myList` unless you propagate them out with something like the event handler you wrote. However, things that bind to the `MyList` property are getting a direct reference to the `BindingList` object, so they will see notifications raised by `myList`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I did suspect as much but I thought I'd check. As you say the BindingList will raise any events to something that binds to it but I shall implement the handler if I need it for something else.

Answer (score 1):

The `INotifyPropertyChange` interface is for notify when change the properties inside a class. For notify when a collection items changes you must use `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Comment: My understanding was that INotifyCollectionChanged was for a collection class rather than a class that has collections. Therefore, this is why I have chosen to use INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: No, i means that you class BindingList must be an ICollectionChanged, the INotifyPropertyChanged do not work if you want to be notified when changed (add/remove) the items of a property that is a collection.